# How and where to pass JSON data as a prop when creating components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting some Club information from a JSON I want to use in my React component 'Club'. I created a component ClubList in which all Club components with their corresponding name should be created but I don't know where I should make the HTTP request and where to save it, so I can use it in the return statement.

I tried saving all titles in an array but I stopped at the point I had to pass the titles to each Club element. I just started working with ReactJS so I am a basically complete beginner in ReactJS (Not in JS though).

This is the ClubList class

```
class ClubList extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
      <div className="Clublist">
        <Club title="Club1" />
        <Club title="Club2" />
        ...
        ...
        ...
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

And that is the Club class

```
  class Club extends React.Component {
     clubProp = {...}

     render() {
        return (
           <div className="Club">
              <div className="image-container">
                 <img src={this.clubProp.imageSrc} width="300px" height="300px"/>
              </div>
              <h2>{this.clubProp.name}</h2>
              <div className="Business-information">
                <div className="Business-address">
                    <p>{this.clubProp.address}</p>
                    <p>{this.clubProp.city}</p>
                    <p>{this.clubProp.zipCode}</p>
                </div>
              <div className="Business-reviews">
                    <h3>{this.clubProp.category}</h3>
                    <h3 className="rating">{this.clubProp.rating}</h3>
                    <p>90 reviews</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I will use an API to get the Club-names but I don't know how I can organize the variables to be accessible in the right places since I don't quite grasp how the scopes in React work. I already have the code for getting the JSON ready, just need to know where to put it and how to pass the values in

Comment: Are you putting the API call in the `Club` component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle method?

Comment: React uses state, which can be passed down through the component tree.  As you are using class components, a typical way of doing this would be to fetch the data in the 'componentDidMount()' lifecyle method, and run `this.setState({clubProp: result.data}) in the fetch/axios callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic syntax would look like the following. Your component will maintain clubs using component state. In the [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle function, you can make your api call and then store the results in your component's state. Any time you call [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), your component will re-render.

```
class ClubList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clubs: []
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const clubs = await this.fetchClubs();
    this.setState({ clubs });
  }

  render() {
    const { clubs } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Clublist">
        {clubs.map(club => (
          <Club title={club.title} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Eventually you can pull out state management from all of your components and use something like [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/) or [`MobX`](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) and let your components focus solely on rendering html.

Answer (score 2):

Where you should make the API request?

Ideally, we use `redux-sagas` or `redux-thunk` as middleware while making API requests. However, since, you're just getting started, you could make the API call in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your `ClubList` component.

Now, I am assuming that you receive an array of `Club`s. You could map over this array and render each `Club` component.

Where you should store this data?

Common practice is to use a state-management library like `redux` with react. It helps scale and maintain your app better. However, you could also use the `state` of the `ClubList` component to store the data of your API call.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will look into redux for long-term after I finished this small project. Would it be just as okay to use props instead of state?

Comment: It is not correct to modify a component's `props` within that component itself. Props are something the component receives from it's parent.
You could use the state of `ClubList` to store the array of `club`s and pass each club down to the `Club` component as a prop.
If you could share a codepen for the same, I'd be glad to explain further.

Comment: Well, the props are stored in Club and I wanted to edit them from ClubList as well as return all Clubs from ClubList so I would change them from another component if I'm not wrong. I have some more Components which are not relevant here but I don't know how to create a codepen with multiple files and a node server

Comment: @SerShubham, nice job.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you make API calls in the componentDidMount life-cycle method. I'd recommend looking at the docs for examples:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

The docs use the browser's fetch method to make the request, but I'd personally recommend using axios. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios, since it's a bit more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

React uses state, which can be passed down through the component tree. As you are using class components, a typical way of getting your JSON data into the app's state would be to fetch the data in the `componentDidMount()` lifecyle method of your top level component, and run `this.setState({clubProp: result.data})` in the fetch/axios callback.  You can pass it to children where they are available as props.

I would argue that Redux is overkill - and that it would be better to defer learning it until you have a state management problem.  The new hooks implementation and context API will also change best practices  for state management.  The guy who created Redux says "Flux libraries are like glasses: you’ll know when you need them."

Answer (score 0):

// Here is the simplified example:

```
class ClubList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ClubDetails: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api link put here in quotes")
                .then(results => {
                    return results.json();
                }).then(data => {
                    let ClubDetails = data;
                    this.setState({ ClubDetails: ClubDetails });
                })
    }
    render() {
        const ClubDetails = this.state.ClubDetails;
        const listItems = ClubDetails.map((clubProp,index) =>
              <Club key={index}  clubProp={clubProp}/>
        );
        return (
            {listItems}
          );
    }
  }
class Club extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <div className="Club">
             <div className="image-container">
                <img src={this.clubProp.imageSrc} width="300px" height="300px"/>
             </div>........
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is using fetch middleware in redux to control all datas in props(You can find in redux github examples), besides the responsive data, you can also monitor fetching status across components.